# Problems on JavaFx：The image doesn't show

Tags: java, image, javafx

I inserted an image object in my code. The program compiles and runs, but the image doesn't show.

[image: window is completely white except for title bar]

Here is my code

```java
package JavaFX;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class ShowImage extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        Image image = new Image(new File("image/v2-7c37a26d9dd77abf6de2ca9ca3fc7ae0_720w.jpg").toURI().toString());//remember this must be an url address,
        // file should be converted to url

        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

        ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView3.setRotate(90);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowImage");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't show any errors or warnings.

Comment: don't see anything obviously wrong .. without throwing an error, the image file lookup seems to be okay. Just a couple of notes for debugging: make the example minimal (a single view without any fluff), use an image with a simple name, make sure the image has the expected size .. in the longer run: do not use file path (except when getting it from user choice, f.i. from a fileChooser) do use resource lookup

Comment: Please take time to format your question properly, it looks like you missed the image markdown. There are good guides available for how to ask good SO questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your code generally works, so the problem is most likely an issue with the image.

You should inspect the `errorProperty` and `exceptionProperty`, for example...

```
if (image.errorProperty().getValue()) {
    image.exceptionProperty().getValue().printStackTrace();
}
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Image image = new Image(new File("image/v2-7c37a26d9dd77abf6de2ca9ca3fc7ae0_720w.jpg").toURI().toString());//remember this must be an url address,
        if (image.errorProperty().getValue()) {
            image.exceptionProperty().getValue().printStackTrace();
        }

        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

        ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView3.setRotate(90);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```